# making a url with the $http using routing params error

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Below is the link of my file. I was unable to generate a url from the existing url generated from `$http`, by using `$parent.$index` and `$index` as ids from routing, please help: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Js5TZf5OXyc1Ivqd4eOh?p=preview)

I have applied the same kind of functionality to another application it worked have a look at this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2p1QFm71U4XOp4sx2IKV?p=preview)

Inside the `loadSingleMatch()` function error in updating the `url` inside the `$http`
error image:- [image]

#### Code

```
app.controller("selfController", ['$http', '$routeParams',
  function($http, $routeParams) {

    //create a context
    var main = this;

    this.parentId = $routeParams.parent;
    this.childId = $routeParams.child;

    console.log(this.parentId);
    console.log(this.childId);

    this.urlOne = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json";

    this.urlTwo = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json";



    this.loadSingleMatch = function() {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: main.urlOne + '/' + main.parentId + '/' + main.childId

      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        main.matchData = response.data.rounds[main.parentId].matches[main.childId];
        console.log(main.matchData);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: link is broken. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've updated the links please check user7294900

Comment: I've edited your question with your second link, it's prefer you add the relevant code in the question

Comment: @user7294900 Please have a look at the problem, I have updated the links and have given the code please check

Answer (score 0):

The a tag should be inside the second ng-repeat:

```
<div class="w3-row w3-hover-shadow w3-hover-border-black w3-border w3-white w3-padding-16" ng-repeat="x in matchDay.matches">                           
                        <a ng-href="#/indiTeam/{{$parent.$index}}/{{$index}}" >
                        <div class="w3-small">
                            <div class="w3-col s6 ">
                                {{x.team1.code}} vs {{x.team2.code}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="w3-col s6">
                                <div class="w3-padding-small">
                                    {{ x.date | date: 'shortDate'}}
                                    ({{$parent.$index}} {{$index}}) 
                                </div>                                      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

See modified plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/PeqUHIZVC0HsqdjLkdOo?p=preview

Comment: I have changed the code but still not able to sort the problem, I'm unable to update the url with the id's($parent.$index and $index) generated from $routeparams and unable to get the data out of it. error 404 NOT FOUND is the error i get when I click on any of the links

Comment: Have you opened my plnkr? it should solve the problem

Comment: The $parent.$index has no relation with the router params, it's related to the ng-repeat $scope.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the answer to my question
the `url` inside the $http should not be changed only the response inside of it needs to be changed 
the `url: main.urlOne` is the change that bought the output as expected